# Is there a way to reply to pull-request review comments with the Github-API V4 (GraphQL)?

Tags: github, github-api, pull-request, github-graphql

#### Goal

I want to use the GraphQL API to reply to a pull request review comment.

It is possible if the status of the review is PENDING, but when the status of the review is SUBMITTED, it is not possible.
When I try it over the UI or the API V3 (REST), everything works fine.

[This](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/35381#discussion_r260056892) is an example of an reply to another PR-review comment.

[This](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/comments/#alternative-input) was the way to do it over the REST API.

#### What I have tried

I have tried to use the GraphQL [addPullRequestReviewComment](https://developer.github.com/v4/mutation/addpullrequestreviewcomment/)
mutation.

Here is my mutation request

```
mutation {
  addPullRequestReviewComment(
    input: {
      pullRequestReviewId: $pullRequestReviewId, 
      inReplyTo: $commentToReplyTo, 
      body: "test comment"
    }) {
        clientMutationId
        comment{
          body
     }
  }
}
```

I expect the above mutation to reply to another review comment, but I get this response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "addPullRequestReviewComment": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "type": "VALIDATION",
      "path": [
        "addPullRequestReviewComment"
      ],
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "message": "Review has already been submitted."
    }
  ]
}
```

I know that when you reply to another PR-Review comment of an already submitted review, you create a new review object for that comment.

But when I would try to solve my problem with that logic I would expect to find a `reply_to` field or some other way to link to a comment of another PR-review comment on the [addPullRequestReviewInput](https://developer.github.com/v4/input_object/addpullrequestreviewinput/) object.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm running into the same problem...

Comment: Yep, the problem is that GraphQL api submits "pending" comment, like this https://p408.p1.n0.cdn.getcloudapp.com/items/04u5GRZg/2f0571fb-038d-462e-9c98-5c5e8dd5a692.jpg?v=1c6a74ced8bf28957ee0a529417f87f9

It requires a second call to "submit review"